# QGIS - Sorting of features in referenced child layer

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS 2.18 and 3.2. I have a point layer (PostGIS) and another layer without geometry. The layers are connected with 1 to many relationship, the parent being the layer with the geometry. Everything is working fine, on the pop-up form  both layers are visible.
The only issue I have is the sorting of the child layer. It doesn't follow any column by default. Of course it can be sorted by clicking on the column label in table view, but the sorting resets every time I close the form.

Any idea how can I set a default sorting by a chosen column?